Errata for "Foliations and Geometric Structures" by Aurel Bejancu and Hani Reda Farran
I'm reading "Foliations and Geometric Structures" (2006) by Aurel Bejancu and Hani Reda Farran and have been looking for an errata sheet.  Unfortunately Prof. Bejancu has passed away. I wrote Prof. Farran at his university email address some time ago, but he appears to have retired and did not respond.  Most of the typos I've found are minor, except for the h in definition (6.2) on p.34 which I suspect should be h'.  A pointer to an errata file or more specifically feedback for (6.2) would be most appreciated.
